# What is the quickest and simplest way for two Arduinos, with network shields, to communicate?

Tags: communication, network

I have two Arduinos, each with a network shield.  What is the quickest and simplest way to connect a cat5 cable between these two Arduinos and have them exchange strings?

Comment: Connect them with a cross-over ethernet cable. Run a client on one and a server on the other. The Ethernet library comes with example clients and servers.

Comment: For clarification: a crossover cable has the green and green/white wires swapped with the orange and orange/white wires at one end. This connects the TX of one end to the RX of the other end and vice versa - just like when you're working with serial.

Comment: Is there a library that can simply send strings back and froth without a client/server?